# Issue with Uncompressing the .7z file in the Android evn

Tags: android, xamarin.android, unzip, 7zip, compression

Getting "system.entrypointnotfoundexception: loadlibrary" While trying to use SevenZipLib.dll to uncompress the .7z file containing media contents/file in the Android evn.

**Context:**
-The whole program is written in c# as a MONO Android Project. No Build/Deployment Error/warnings.
While running the apk, its throwing "system.entrypointnotfoundexception: loadlibrary".
-Also tested the same code as windows project (not mono) - uncompressing in the windows evn.

**Assumptions for the issue:**
7zip internally might be using COM components & Mono frame work is not supporting.

**Question:**

Has anyone come across similar issue? Please suggest some alternative dll/framework which can be used by my apk for uncompressing the .7z file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `SevenZipLib.dll` is the [SevenZipLib Library on CodePlex](http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/), the problem is [SevenZipLib\SevelZipLib\SevenZipArchive.cs](http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60434#1534264):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern SafeLibraryHandle LoadLibrary(
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpFileName);
```

The project contains numerous P/Invokes into `kernel32.dll` (`LoadLibrary()`, `GetProcAddress()`, `FreeLibrary()`), `ole32.dll` (`PropVariantClear()`), `oleaut32.dll` (`SafeArrayCreateVector()`), and more.

In short, this library is intimately tied to Windows, and isn't going to work on a non-Windows platform in any meaningful fashion, not without a lot of work.

If you need 7z support in a Mono for Android application, you'll need to look into a different library. It looks like the [7-zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) includes C# source for reading LZMA files that doesn't rely on P/Invoke, so perhaps that would work?

Comment: Anyone sucessfully used the 7zip SDK C# version with M4A?